# OpenCv 3.1.0 - compile fails

Tags: linux, debian, opencv3.0

I'm trying to install OpenCv  3.1.0 on debian 8 (it provides python3 bindings)

following the standard procedure on the official site http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html   the process  fails

```
[ 30%] Building CXX object modules/photo/CMakeFiles/opencv_photo.dir/opencl_kernels_photo.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_shape.so
[ 30%] Built target opencv_shape
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_photo.so
[ 30%] Built target opencv_photo
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[  0%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  0%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[  4%] Built target opencv_core
[  4%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[  4%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[  4%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  4%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[  9%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[  9%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[  9%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgcodecs
[ 11%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 11%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[ 11%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(avpacket.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:280: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.1.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4076: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**more info about this issue at http://wiki.open-si.org/trac-notes/ticket/10**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes from some of libraries used by ffpmeg do not compile with --enable-shared most probably the libvpx, please use "make clean" first before you reset ./configure with --enable-shared and recompile those libraries.

```
make clean
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
make
sudo make install
```

Another option assuming that you don't use FFMPEG with OpenCV: you can disable it from being compiled:

When you run Cmake i.e.:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin \
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

Add the flag `-DWITH_FFMPEG=0` to not compile the FFMPEG part

Comment: compiling FFMPEG with --enable-shared fixed the issue.

Comment: where do you run the .configure command?